# How to Disable a Module in a specific store in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2

I have a question, guys. Is it possible to disable a module in a specific store view? Also, this is a multistore site with different themes for each store.

If you guys have ideas please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Unless the module comes with an enable/disable setting that can be set per store view this is to my knowledge not something Magento provides as an out of the box capability.